# Need to access the <td> with the help of the classname

Tags: html, html-table

I need to apply styles to the entire row based on some condition check on the class name.

My table structure looks like:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><div><span class='level2'></span></div></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div><span class='level90'></span></div></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I need to apply the styles to the rest of the <td> in a row that contains class name as 'level2' in the first <td>.

How do I traverse through the <tr> till the <span> and apply the styles to the <td>'s of same row?

I did try something:

```
var els = document.getElementById("ratiosTable").getElementsByClassName("Level2");
            console.log(els);

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
   els[i].style.fontWeight = "bold"
}
```

Comment: and what was the result of your approach, why did it not work for you. what was the issue?

Comment: It is returning me the span, I want the <tr> that contains the span of Level2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPTION 1**

You can iterate the rows and check that it has a child of the expected class.

```js
var rows = document.getElementById("ratiosTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");

console.log(rows);
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
  if(rows[i].getElementsByClassName("level2").length > 0) {
    rows[i].style.fontWeight = "bold"
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="ratiosTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div><span class='level2'>Bold</span></div>
      </td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div><span class='level90'>Not Bold</span></div>
      </td>
      <td>N</td>
      <td>N</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**OPTION 2**

**This does not work on  IE** but does on all other major browsers including Edge. For more information : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

```js
var els = document.getElementById("ratiosTable").getElementsByClassName("level2");
            console.log(els);

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
//NOTE closest
   els[i].closest("tr").style.fontWeight = "bold"
}
```

```html
<table id="ratiosTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div><span class='level2'>Bold</span></div>
      </td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div><span class='level90'>Not Bold</span></div>
      </td>
      <td>N</td>
      <td>N</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```